# run graylog in different port

Tags: graylog

Hi I used openstack qcow2 format and run the graylog server

Now I can access my openstack machine only using floating public IP address and not via private Internal IP address.

Here when I do graylog using public Ip address I get the following error,

```
"http://172.29.18.94:9000/api/"
```

Which is actually my private IP address.

How can i change IP and port should be in 8080, I followed document "http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.4/pages/installation/openstack.html" to install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `/etc/graylog/server/server.conf`

Change the `web_listen_uri` and `rest_listen_uri` lines:

```
web_listen_uri = http://ip_address:8080/
rest_listen_uri = http://ip_address:8080/api/
```

`ip_address`will obviously be replaced with the address that you want to use. You'll also need to allow port 8080 through your firewall and restart the service for `graylog`.